# Returning multiple rows manufactured in a LOOP in Postgres 14.7 stored function

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, resultset

## Original Question

I'm writing a PL/PgSQL function to take an `ltree` and break out subtrees of various lengths. I'm going to run this against a sample of some real data to get frequency counts on subtrees, regardless of their position in the path/tree.

I'm getting hung up on *returning* the results. I can generate what I want okay, I just can't figure out how to get them into a returned result. I don't mind using `CREATE TYPE`, although `RETURNS TABLE` seems like it should be enough. I'd rather not use `RETURN SETOF record`, if possible.

I've tried lots of permutations, but without luck. Can someone spot my error? Here's the function code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tools.ltree_subtrees (ltree, int4);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tools.ltree_subtrees (
     source_tree       ltree,
     shortest_subtree  int4  DEFAULT 3) -- 1 & 2 explode out the result set size.

RETURNS TABLE (
          substree_start    int4,
          subtree           text)

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
-- Unwind the packed.ltree.values into a text[array].
-- Efficient? Doubt it. Plenty of options for production.
label_array         text[] := string_to_array(ltree2text(source_tree), '.');

source_tree_length  int4   := nlevel(source_tree);
subtree_size        int4   := shortest_subtree;

out_row             record;

BEGIN

-- Loop over the whole label array, sliding from position 1 to the end
FOR subtree_size IN shortest_subtree..source_tree_length LOOP

RAISE NOTICE 'subtree_size(%) ', subtree_size;

    FOR label_index IN 1..(source_tree_length - subtree_size + 1) LOOP

            SELECT label_index,
              label_array [label_index : label_index + subtree_size - 1],
              label_index,
              subtree_size
          
         INTO out_row;

    RETURN NEXT;

    RAISE NOTICE 'out_row = (%)', out_row;

    END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END
$BODY$;
```

Here's a sample call with output:

```
select * from ltree_subtrees(text2ltree('My.Best.Dog.Is.Named.Lilli'));

/*
+----------------+---------+
| substree_start | subtree |
+----------------+---------+
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
| NULL           | NULL    |
+----------------+---------+
*/
```

That looks like the right result row count, but the contents are all `NULL`. The `RAISE NOTICE` reports shows I'm generating the outputs I want....I'm just not *outputing* them.

```
Initializing connection...
Connection ready. Took 0.054 seconds.

NOTICE:  subtree_size(3)
NOTICE:  out_row = ((1,"{My,Best,Dog}",1,3))
NOTICE:  out_row = ((2,"{Best,Dog,Is}",2,3))
NOTICE:  out_row = ((3,"{Dog,Is,Named}",3,3))
NOTICE:  out_row = ((4,"{Is,Named,Lilli}",4,3))
NOTICE:  subtree_size(4)
NOTICE:  out_row = ((1,"{My,Best,Dog,Is}",1,4))
NOTICE:  out_row = ((2,"{Best,Dog,Is,Named}",2,4))
NOTICE:  out_row = ((3,"{Dog,Is,Named,Lilli}",3,4))
NOTICE:  subtree_size(5)
NOTICE:  out_row = ((1,"{My,Best,Dog,Is,Named}",1,5))
NOTICE:  out_row = ((2,"{Best,Dog,Is,Named,Lilli}",2,5))
NOTICE:  subtree_size(6)
NOTICE:  out_row = ((1,"{My,Best,Dog,Is,Named,Lilli}",1,6))
SELECT 10
Statement completed successfully. (10 results). 0.009 seconds. (Line 1).

Finished. Total time: 0.064 seconds.
```

I'm hopeful that I'm missing something simple . I've tried `RETURN SETOF record`, `RETURN NEXT`, `RETURN NEXT row_out` (parameter not allowed error.)

Thanks for any help.

## Final Version

Help received! I'm posting a corrected version of the function, only to show the syntax involved in looping, building synthetic rows, and returning them. The function itself if a bit...dubious. Still, good enough for some experiments.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ltree_subtrees (ltree, int4);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ltree_subtrees (
     source_tree       ltree,
     shortest_subtree  int4  DEFAULT 3) -- 1 & 2 explode out the result set size.

RETURNS TABLE (
     subtree_start     int4,
     subtree           ltree)

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    label_array            text[] := string_to_array(ltree2text(source_tree), '.');
    source_tree_length     int4   := nlevel(source_tree);
    subtree_size           int4   := shortest_subtree;

BEGIN

FOR subtree_size IN shortest_subtree..source_tree_length LOOP

    FOR label_index IN 1..(source_tree_length - subtree_size + 1) LOOP

        -- Do *not* build a record, assign the variables declared in the RETURNS TABLE
        -- clause and then RETURN NEXT to append that to the output.
        subtree_start := label_index;
        subtree       := text2ltree(array_to_string(label_array [label_index : label_index + subtree_size - 1], '.'));

    RETURN NEXT;

    END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END
$BODY$;

-- Try it:
select subtree_start,
       subtree,
       nlevel(subtree) as subtree_length

  from ltree_subtrees(text2ltree('My.Best.Dog.Is.Named.Lilli'))

/*
+---------------+----------------------------+----------------+
| subtree_start | subtree                    | subtree_length |
+---------------+----------------------------+----------------+
| 1             | My.Best.Dog                | 3              |
| 2             | Best.Dog.Is                | 3              |
| 3             | Dog.Is.Named               | 3              |
| 4             | Is.Named.Lilli             | 3              |
| 1             | My.Best.Dog.Is             | 4              |
| 2             | Best.Dog.Is.Named          | 4              |
| 3             | Dog.Is.Named.Lilli         | 4              |
| 1             | My.Best.Dog.Is.Named       | 5              |
| 2             | Best.Dog.Is.Named.Lilli    | 5              |
| 1             | My.Best.Dog.Is.Named.Lilli | 6              |
+---------------+----------------------------+----------------+
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign values to the output variables `subtree` and `subtree_start` before calling `RETURN NEXT`.